# How to remove gcm id from server which is not used

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for my app.Every thing is working fine.If there is a situation clear the cache and install the same application,It will generate the new unique GCM id and I will send it to sever, and my question is how can i remove the old GCM id.I want to remove old unused GCM ID from my server because when i want send the notification to multiple devices this unused id is also included.I came across the  pubSub.unsubscribe,But it is for topics. Can any one tell me how can i remove old GCM id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your server tries to send a message using the invalid token you should get a response that indicates as such. At that point you should be able to delete the invalid token from your server.

Comment: Thanks friend.I did the same thing as I was getting response Not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Override  onTokenRefresh() of InstanceIDListenerService to update the new GCM ID

Comment: I can see onTokenRefresh() is implemented in MyInstanceIDListenerService class how can i use it

Comment: should i compare both the gcm id and when is this method called

Comment: When you store the GCM ID the first time in a DB you would have had a unique identifier for that person which would be his/her user id... So what you will essentially do in onTokenRefresh(), get the new token id, get the user id of the person and update the DB. Hope this helps.